# How to use who V.S. whom

Tags: whom, who

Can someone explain how to use how V.S. whom? Please give an example for both, please!

Answer (score -1):

*Who* is for a subject, *whom* is for a direct or indirect object).

A trick for remembering this is to replace *who* with *he* or *she*, and *whom* with *him* or *her*.

Subject: *He* gave you flowers? -> *Who* gave you flowers?

Direct Object: You called *him*? -> *Whom* did you call?

Indirect Object: You gave flowers to *him*? -> To *whom* did you give flowers?

Comment: The downvote is probably because "Whom did you call?" is probably near-obsolete in formal contexts nowadays (though it might be for lack of any supporting reference). But the 'who' vs 'whom' debate has been done to death on here. Twice at least (done to death that is, not addressed). I think the consensus is only to use 'whom' immediately after a preposition, and to try to avoid even this usage.

Comment: Then shouldn't the downvote be reserved for the question, and not for the person trying to help? And the question does not specify if they mean formally or informally.

Comment: Is it best to leave unexplained downvotes without an attempted explanation, would you say?

Comment: The downvote (not me) may be because this question should be closed as duplicate instead of being answered.

Comment: Downvoting an answer because you don't like the question doesn't really encourage newbies to participate and contribute, does it?